VSFTP: "open for write: permission denied" but directory has full permissions
My problem is as follows: I have a Windows PC connecting to a remote Debian 12 Linux server, to transfer files between the two I connect via FileZilla (on windows) to the vsftpd server on the remote. I can connect successfully to the server over TLS (as sftp://ftpuser@IP) and can navigate through to a parent FTP directory which I made /home/ftpuser/.
When I try to transfer or create a file from my pc to the remote then I get the following error:
Command: put "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\FILE_TO_TRANSFER.iso" "FILE_TO_TRANSFER.iso"
Error:   /home/ftpuser/FILE_TO_TRANSFER.iso: open for write: permission denied
Error:   File transfer failed

Which is strange because I have given the directory read/write access on the Linux server:
~# chmod -R a+rw /home/ftpuser/
~# chown ftpuser /home/ftpuser/
~# ls -ld /home/ftpuser/

> drw-rw-rw- 4 ftpuser ftpuser 4096 Jul 23 10:15 /home/fptuser/

Additionally there are two sub-directories ("ftp_dir" and "transfers") in /home/ftpuser/ which I cannot see from my windows FileZilla.
~# cd /home/ftpuser
/home/ftpuser# ls

> ftp_dir transfers

Additionally, I have also tried with full read/write/execute (chmod -R 777 /home/ftpuser/) permissions but the problem persisted.
My vsftpd.conf file has the following (summarized) configuration:
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp_dir
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO

So if ftpuser has all the read/write permissions to a directory, why would I not be able to create or transfer files to that directory? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure .. Are you sure you set the read/write access on the correct folder since you are chrooting ?
